# pass a list by reference in R function

Tags: r

I have a simple recursion function in R that would modify its input arguments. I use eval.parent(substitute()) in order to apply the changes on the arguments, However I get this error:
"invalid (do_set) left-hand side to assignment "
Does anyone know how to fix this error?
Here is my function:

```
decompose_clade=function(ind,Small_clades_ind,Remove_tips,Clades){
  Ch=Children(tree,ind)
  if(Ch[1]<length(tree$tip.label)){
    l=Remove_tips
    l=c(l,Ch[1])
    eval.parent(substitute(Remove_tips=l))
    print("tip added=")
    print(Ch[1])
  }else if(length(extract.clade(tree,Ch[1])$tip.label)<4){
    s=Small_clades_ind
    s=c(s,Ch[1])
    eval.parent(substitute(Small_clades_ind=s))
    print("small clade added=")
    print(Ch[1])
  }else if(length(extract.clade(tree,Ch[1])$tip.label)>80){
    decompose_clade(Ch[1],Small_clades_ind,Remove_tips,Clades)
    print("function calls again")
  }else{
   m=Clades
   m=c(m,Ch[1])
    eval.parent(substitute(Clades<-m))
    print("a clade added=")
    print(Ch[1])
  }

}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is no easy way to have pass-by-reference behaviours in R, with only one exception: `environment`. I'm not sure if `environment` suits your need, you can give it a try:

```
modify_input <- function(x){
    x$z <- 1
}

x <- new.env(parent = emptyenv())
modify_input(x)
x$z
```

As to the usage, `environment` supports `e$z` and `e[["z"]]` and `length(e)` just like `list`, but it doesn't support `e[[1]]` and things like that. You can think of `environment` as a dictionary and elements in it have no order. If you want to list all the elements in an `environment`, you can use `ls`. And there are ways to transform `environment` to `list` (`as.list`) and vise versa (`list2env`). Hope it can help.

Answer (score 0):

May be you can follow the following approach.

```
x <- 1
fn <- function() {
    x <<- 2 
}
```

Now `x` is 2.